# Moving SQL Logins

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a question about SQL Logins. If we have to move the users from one server to another how can we do that? Also do we have to change anything after

it is moved? Please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to transfer the logins and the passwords between instances of SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992)